# How does "stop and identify statutes" work in the US?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, police, identification

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFOIWjODOIo). The video is pretty long, but basically it is alleged that a guy keeps harrassing a men that is eating in a restaurant (calling him repeatedly, etc.). The man calls the police, the police shows up, and nothing happens.

So I got curious why the police didn't ask his ID, and read the [stop and identify statues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_and_identify_statutes) wikipedia page.

I don't know in which US State the incident in the Youtube video occurred, but some things from the Wikipedia page are not clear to me. For example:

> In 12 states (Alabama, Delaware, Illinois, Kansas, Missouri, Nebraska,
> New Hampshire, New York, North Dakota, Rhode Island, Utah, Wisconsin),
> police "may demand" identifying information. Of note, though, in New
> Hampshire for example (RSA 594:2), statutory language authorizing a
> 'demand' for identity **does not establish a legal requirement to
> provide documentation of identity (ID), or even a requirement to
> respond in the first place**.

So in New Hampshire a police officer may DEMAND my identification from me, and I may simply ignore him/her without committing a crime? Is my understanding correct? How does these statutes work out in general?

If my understanding is correct, suppose I am a gentlemen being harrassed, and Mr. X is doing the harrassment to me: he is outside my door, he is calling my phone number repeatedly, he is repeatedly knocking on my door, he is repeatedly shouting my name out, he is repeatedly calling me a child molester, he is repeatedly shouting that my mum does a job not to be proud of, etc.

I call the police. The police shows up. I tell the police I want to file charges for harrassment against the guy in front of me (Mr. X, but I don't yet know his name). The police asks Mr. X for his identification. Mr. X will repond that "statutory language [...] does not establish a legal requirement to provide documentation of identity (ID)".

End of it. End of my charges.

Is that correct?

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure that the stop and identify situations occur when there is no obvious crime being committed. That's wouldn't be true in your situation.

Comment: @mkennedy reasonable suspicion is necessary in any case; statutory requirements do not supersede the fourth amendment.  See the answers to the linked duplicate.

Comment: If you don't know the jurisdiction of the interaction, we can't possibly guess whether the officer discretionarily declines to ask for ID, or is this a legal issue. You can read the specifics on ID laws in the other question. The second part of your question contains the germ of a separate question, namely what acts of "harassment" could justify an arrest. Producing ID is tangential; the phone-calling fact potentially renders production of ID irrelevant.

Comment: @user6726 [my other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58403/how-will-the-stop-and-identify-statute-work-in-new-hampshire-in-this-particula) specify the jurisdiction as New Hampshire, if you want to take a look